# complex conjugate; prove that $|z+w| \leq |z|+|w|$

Tags: complex-numbers

Prove that $|z+w| \leq |z|+|w|$.

Okay so I labeled $z$ as $z=a+bi$ and $w$ as $w=c+di$. Substituting and solving for everything I got $\sqrt{(a+c)^2 + (b+d)^2} \leq \sqrt{a^2 +b^2} + \sqrt{c^2 +d^2}$. I know if I plug in numbers that this statement is true but is there a way to say this in a simpler way?

Comment: you are being asked to prove complex triangle inequality. try reading this [article](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~forehand/67_summer2012_files/triangle%20inequality.pdf)

Comment: usually it helps to look at $|z|^2 = z^*z$ since square roots are annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to prove that $|z+w|^2 \leq (|z| + |w|)^2$, which is an equivalent statement. The left side of the inequality is $$(z+w)(\overline{z} + \overline{w}) = |z|^2 + z \overline{w} + w \overline{z} + |w|^2.$$ On the other hand, we have $$(|z| + |w|)^2 = |z|^2 + 2|z||w| + |w|^2.$$ Try to compare the terms in the middle.